# Get data after the third forward slash in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a url https://192.168.1.243/admin/build/take_control. I need to get the string before third occurrence of /, here what I need is https://192.168.1.243.

Comment: Please explain the problem clearly and your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var input = 'https://192.168.1.243/admin/build/take_control';
var output = input.match(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/)[0]
console.log(output);
```

it will work if you have http or https at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are always dealing with a URL, and don't want to use regex, you could use the URL.origin.

```js
var url = "https://192.168.1.243/admin/build/take_control";
var base = new URL(url).origin;
console.log(base);
```

as @Tushar noted, it is important to realise that this is not supported in all browser. (But [most of them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Browser_compatibility) do).